# ManagementException Quota violation, Call cancelled, Provider load failure

Tags: c#, wmi

During past half of the year three users had problem which you can see below.

```
(Error, 27.11.2014 15:47:53+01:00) The request for Windows processes was terminated by an error.
System.Management.ManagementException: Quota violation 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.CreateForJoin(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__61`4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at XY.IsProcessFromDirectoryRunning(String directory)
(Error, 27.11.2014 15:47:53+01:00) The request for Windows processes was terminated by an error.
System.Management.ManagementException: Call cancelled 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.CreateForJoin(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__61`4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at XY.IsProcessFromDirectoryRunning(String directory)
(Error, 27.11.2014 15:47:53+01:00) The request for Windows processes was terminated by an error.
System.Management.ManagementException: Provider load failure 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.CreateForJoin(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__61`4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at XY.IsProcessFromDirectoryRunning(String directory)
(Error, 27.11.2014 15:47:53+01:00) The request for Windows processes was terminated by an error.
System.Management.ManagementException: Provider load failure 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.CreateForJoin(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__61`4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at XY.IsProcessFromDirectoryRunning(String directory)
```

The **Provider load failure** exception persists until shutdown of the application or until CTD due to memory leak (which is caused by this problem). Also I am not able to reproduce this problem, I tried call this method from test application +/- 1,5M times, but it was without problem.

Method should be OK, but you can see it below:

```
public static IEnumerable<Process> GetProcessesFromDirectory(string directory)
{
    if (directory.Last() != Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
    {
        directory += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    }

    var wmiQueryString = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process";

    try
    {
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        {
            return
                from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                join managementObject in searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                    on process.Id equals (int)(uint)managementObject["ProcessId"]
                let processExecutable = (string)managementObject["ExecutablePath"]
                where processExecutable != null && processExecutable.StartsWith(directory, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                select process;
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Process>();
    }
}

public bool IsProcessFromDirectoryRunning(string directory)
{
    try
    {
        return this.GetProcessesFromDirectory(directory).Any();
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        this.logger.Log(ex, Strings.ProcessSearchError);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Question is if I am getting *Provider load failure* can I somehow restart it? I tried to find answer on google, but I didn't find anything useful. I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Do not think I'm rude. Form erased my greeting and I can not edit it. Don't know why. :/

Comment: You are asking for too much data from WMI, so you are violating a quota.  It is a low one for processes, iterating them is pretty expensive.  Could be that you are running this code from multiple threads, could be that the machine has too many active processes, could be that you run this query too often.

Comment: Thanks man, you direct me on the right path.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to help others. You can even mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will read it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found that use Process.GetProcesses() and there use MainModule.FilePath is much more faster then check processes through WMI, so problems with WMI will be gone.

```
return Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Id > 4 && !p.HasExited && p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(directory));
```